# Obter valores numéricos do banco de dados com vírgula e pontos [FIREBIRD + C#]

Tags: c#, firebird, datagridview

Olá, a todos. Estou com problemas ao obter os valores numéricos do banco de dados no meu `Datagridview` com os mesmos já formatados (incluindo vírgulas e pontos).

O código que faz a obtenção dos dados através de uma procedure e adiciona no meu `Datagridview` é:

```
 string sql = "SELECT * FROM BUSCA_DETALHES_CARTEIRA(1, '1-JAN-2017', '31-JAN-2019', '1', 'N')";

        using (FbCommand command_ObtemDadosRel = new FbCommand(sql, ConexaoAoBanco))
        {
            ConexaoAoBanco.Open();

            using (IDataReader reader = command_ObtemDadosRel.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader[2]));

                }
            }
        }
```

Os valores diretamente no meu banco de dados ficam formatados já (com pontos e vírgulas):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém no  `Datagridview`fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os detalhes são: Já tentei utilizar a opção de conversão para `Decimal` `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(reader[2]));`

Pois o comando de `GetTypeCode`do `Reader`, me retorna que é do tipo `Decimal`

Mas mesmo assim também tentei o `Convert.ToDouble(reader[2]))`,  `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader.GetDecimal(2).ToString())`, `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader.GetDouble(2).ToString());` e também `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader.GetFloat(2).ToString())` somente para descargo de consciência. Ambos não deram certo.

Esta coluna do meu banco de dados onde eu faço a leitura e adiciono no `Datagridview` os registros é do tipo `Numeric`.

Como posso fazer para obter os valores já com vírgulas e pontos? Preciso ajustar algo na hora da leitura dos dados ou é alguma propriedade do próprio `Datagridview`?

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n";

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, mas esse código deve ficar onde? Em qual evento?

Comment: Eu sou iniciante.